# Django not displaying images from blog Post

Tags: django, blogs

I have created a DJANGO blog-engine which takes my post and the template parses it for html tags. links etc.. are working but it does not load image file and instead shows the 'alternative' . I have tried the tag in separate html files and it is otherwise. Just not displaying image from inside a django blog post.

Relevant portions of the template file :

```
{% include 'blog/header.html' %}
</aside>
<section id ="content">
<article>
{%for post in posts %}
  <h2><a href="{{ post_get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
  <h3>{{ post.created}}</h3>
  <p> 
  {{ post.body|safe }}<br>
  </p>
  <h3>By {{ post.author }}</h3>
```

I am copy-pasting the post in question

```
<---- text here ------------------>
<a href="http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1Directory.html">GDCM::Directory</a>
<img src="/home/usman/www/deejay/blog/static/images/dicomdir.png" />

This is it
```

Interestingly, the 'a' tag works fine but the 'img' tag is  not working. I have tried many variations but i want some inline code to display simple html tag, alternatively of course i will resort to it programmatically by passing some variable to the template from inside the post to let it know where to position the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I replaced the full address with

```
       <img src="/static/images/dicomdir.png"/>
```

On development server as well as on production. What helped was that I looked at the Dev-server responses on my terminal and was able to figure out the url.

Comment: You should probably be using the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` tag. `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/dicomdir.png"/>` just make sure you have your settings properly adjusted. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `{{ post_get_absolute_url }}`. You should use `{{ post.get_absolute_url }}`.

The better way is to call the URL of the image directly; that way you maintain your URLs in `urls.py` and not in your model code. It makes your app more portable.

Take your image field name value from your model, and then `{{ post.image.url }}`. For example, if your model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Then you would use `{{ post.img.url }}`